# FBInstant.shareAsync( ) failed with 500

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I'm doing the sharing in my instant game. 
I'm firing next req from the game:

```
FBInstant.shareAsync(
{
    intent: 'REQUEST',
    image: 'image-encoded-here',
    text: 'Edgar just played BASH for 9 points!',
    data: { myReplayData: 'message sent' },
}
).then( function()
{
    console.log("sharing is done");
})
.catch( function(err)
{
   console.log('failed to share: ' + err.code + " :: " + err.message);
});
```

but I'm receiving 500-error:

https://www.facebook.com/games/quicksilver/share_score/?dpr=2 500 ()
failed to share: NETWORK_FAILURE ::

=====================================

in My particulare case problems was with encoded image. 
As i remember, image to share should include all the encoded image stuff with "data:image/jpeg;base64,/" in front.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @eliezer-berlin
in my case problem was with encoded image. As i remember, you have to share all the encoded image stuff( with "data:image/jpeg;base64,/" in front).

Comment: That was my problem as well. It looks like that is the correct solution.

Answer (score -1):

Look at your "image" parameter in the shareAsync(). You must send a Base64 url or it will go wrong.

Comment: Despite you actually giving the correct solution, it appears you're getting downvoted because your answer was too vague and uninformative. I'm sorry to see that.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the "," from the line

```
data: { myReplayData: 'message sent' },
data: { myReplayData: 'message sent' }
```

Comment: -1; trailing commas in object literals are legal in modern JavaScript, so there's no need to remove this one, and there's no plausible way that one could cause a 500 error from a remote server anyway.